# Are some non-coding RNA spliced?

Tags: molecular-genetics, rna, splicing, noncoding-rna

Are some non-coding RNA spliced like mRNA? I tried to find some information but I don't find anything...

Comment: yes yes - many of them are spliced out of mRNA too

Answer (score 9):

You should check out [**Howald C**, *et al*<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/gr.134478.111).  This is one of the many recent papers tied to the [ENCODE data](http://www.nature.com/encode/). They've used RT-PCR to amplify exon-exon junctions and then sequenced the results. Supplemental table 2 shows 3076 validated exon-exon junctions in putative processed transcripts which, in the main body of the paper may be sub-classified as:

> Non-coding, 3prime_overlapping_ncrna, Ambiguous_orf, Antisense,
>   LincRNA, ncRNA_host, Retained_intron, Sense_intronic,
>   Sense_overlapping, Processed transcript.

1. [**Howald C, Tanzer A, Chrast J, Kokocinski F, Derrien T, Walters N, Gonzalez JM, Frankish A, Aken BL, Hourlier T, Vogel JH, White S, Searle S, Harrow J, Hubbard TJ, Guigó R, Reymond A**. 2012. Combining RT-PCR-seq and RNA-seq to catalog all genic elements encoded in the human genome. Genome Research, 22: 1698–1710, doi:10.1101/gr.134478.111](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/gr.134478.111).

Answer (score 4):

Do you call ribosomal RNA non-coding? rRNA is spliced both in prokaryotes and eukaryotes.

Comment: can you give some reference, please?

Comment: Sure. Some general information on pre-tRNA and pre-rRNA processing from Molecular Cell Biology: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21729/

Comment: And of course rRNA is non-coding. Coding refers  specifically to sequences coding for protein.

Comment: One of my teachers considered all "functional" RNA coding.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, check out [HOTAIR](http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?position=chr12:54356096-54362515&hgsid=298485341&knownGene=pack&hgFind.matches=uc009zne.3,) (in human), as well as [cyrano and megamind](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867411014504) in zebrafish -- they are all spliced.